# using a list of words for python script

Tags: python, parsing

I try to use the following python script to get parsed data from a german online dictonary called 'Duden'.

https://github.com/radomirbosak/duden

The syntax is:

```
import duden
w = duden.get(word)
print(w.title)
print(w.name)
print(w.article)
print(w.part_of_speech)
print(w.frequency)
print(w.usage)
print(w.word_separation)
print(w.meaning_overview)
print(w.synonyms)
print(w.origin)
```

Now I want to pass a list of words (where every word is written in a seperate row) to this script which than will get the data from every word and save it in a seperate file for each word like word.json.

How would I implement this process in the python script?
Is it possible to drop words which get an Attribute error because they do not exist in the dictonary?

Thank You
vitalore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
import duden
import json

words = ["Loeffel", "Garten", "Morgen"]

for word in words:
        result = {}
        w = duden.get(word)
        if w is not None:
                result['title'] = w.title
                result['name'] = w.name
                result['article'] = w.article
                print(result)

        with open(f'{word}.json', 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(json.dumps(result), fp)
```

Comment: cool. thank you! I dont know much about json.. How could I get the json dumps in a better format like name = Garten or something? Also how can I pass a word list in txt format instead of a list inside the code to the script?